# Trying to use Math.floor to round numbers but it doesn't cut them off at the right point

Tags: java, math, rounding-error

I am trying to use Math.floor to round a quotient to 1, 2, and 3 places but it wont cut the numbers off at the right place

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double x;
    double y;


    System.out.println("Enter 2 values seperated by a space, x and y to enter into the eqation: (x/y).");
    x = input.nextDouble();
    y = input.nextDouble();

    for(int i = 1; i < 4.0; i++){
        double z = Math.floor((x/y)* (10^i) + 0.5) / (10^i);
        System.out.println(z);

    }
```

Here is one of the outputs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBod0.jpg

Comment: why not use Math.round?

Comment: I have to use Math.floor :/ I realize math.round would be easier but im not supposed to use it.

Comment: And don't you need `Math.pow(10,i)` instead of `(10^i)`?

Comment: Do you realize that you are using bitwise exclusive or operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Math.pow(10, i), because ^ is a bitwise operator:

```
double z = Math.floor((x/y)* Math.pow(10,i) + 0.5) / Math.pow(10,i);
```

Answer (score 1):

10^i does not mean exponentiation in Java. It means bitwise XOR. You should use Math.Pow(10, i).

Comment: Thank you! I had tried Math.pow earlier but i think I messed up a parenthesis with the Math.floor and got another error but with the fix I made in the Math.floor and changing back to Math.pow worked!

Comment: @user3579593 Glad it worked. Please be sure to accept an answer so the next person with the same question can find it. All the best.